I have this error in ROS2 jazzy [ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executed command failed
I have been trying to manage ROS2 with urdf files by this tutorial:
https://automaticaddison.com/create-and-visualize-a-robotic-arm-with-urdf-ros-2-jazzy/
I tried many times to follow the commands but some of them I follow the lines: (try by yourself to work and continue with the tutorial)

build by colcon build
source ~/.bashrc by source ~/ros2_ws2/install/setup.bash

but when I run the line:

ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py
model:=/home/steveen/ros2_ws/src/mycobot_ros2/mycobot_description/urdf/robots/mycobot_280.urdf.xacro

I got the path of the mycobot_280.urdf.xacro by run pwd to make sure the model urdf's path but I got this mistake: (it should open Rviz)


[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below
/home/steveen/.ros/log/2024-11-19-19-04-28-909302-steven-ubuntu2404-27875
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for
traceback): executed command failed. Command: xacro
/home/steveen/ros2_ws/src/mycobot_ros2/mycobot_description/urdf/robots/mycobot_280.urdf.xacro
Captured stderr output: error: No such file or directory:
/home/steveen/ros2_ws/install/mycobot_description/share/mycobot_description/urdf/control/gazebo_sim_ros2_control.urdf.xacro
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/home/steveen/ros2_ws/install/mycobot_description/share/mycobot_description/urdf/control/gazebo_sim_ros2_control.urdf.xacro'
when processing file:
/home/steveen/ros2_ws/src/mycobot_ros2/mycobot_description/urdf/robots/mycobot_280.urdf.xacro


In the error 4 from the terminal I cannot see the file /home/steveen/ros2_ws/install/mycobot_description/share/mycobot_description/urdf/control/gazebo_sim_ros2_control.urdf.xacro that means that I install gazebo.. I installed gazebo but why the gazebo_sim_ros2_control.urdf.xacro, I should create that file?..
considering that I run ubuntu 24.04 ROS2 jazzy in Oracle Virtualbox.
How can I fix that problem?
